# Is the flink MapState's TTL for the whole MapState instance or for each element in the MapState

Tags: state, apache-flink, ttl

I have a MapState in flink. And I set the ttl to 10 minutes. Is the ttl for the whole MapState instance or for each of the elements?

```
    val ttlConfig = StateTtlConfig
      .newBuilder(Time.minutes(10))
      .setUpdateType(StateTtlConfig.UpdateType.OnCreateAndWrite)
      .setStateVisibility(StateTtlConfig.StateVisibility.NeverReturnExpired)
      .build

      val myMapState: MapState[String, Upload] = ....

      myMapState.put("a", "x")

      // 5 minutes later
      myMapState.put("b", "y")

      // Again 6 minutes later, is the myMapState still available? 
      // I assume myMapState is still available and it still has key "b" for 4 minutes. Is that correct?
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hi your assumption is correct .

> If a TTL is configured and a state value has expired, the stored
>   value will be cleaned up on a best effort basis.

So the value might still be stored even if the TTL has passed  , the state visibility  configuration will control if the value will be  returned or not .

- StateTtlConfig.StateVisibility.NeverReturnExpired - expired value is 
  never returned
- StateTtlConfig.StateVisibility.ReturnExpiredIfNotCleanedUp - returned
  if still available

More info about [state TTL](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/dev/stream/state/state.html#state-time-to-live-ttl)

Comment: What happens when before the expired key could be removed, we added the key again, effectively refreshing its last updated time to eg.t. Will it stay until t + 10 or it will still be removed?

Comment: It will stay since the TTL will be updated. You could config the TTL update `policy:setUpdateType(StateTtlConfig.UpdateType.OnCreateAndWrite)`

Answer (score 1):

Yes, flink supports ttl per entry.

> State Time-To-Live (TTL)
> A time-to-live (TTL) can be assigned to the keyed state of any type. If a TTL is ? configured and a state value has expired, the stored value will be cleaned up on a best  effort basis which is discussed in more detail below.

> **All state collection types support per-entry TTLs. This means that list elements and map entries expire independently.**

https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/dev/stream/state/state.html#state-time-to-live-ttl